# Is it redundant to use "or not" at the end of a sentence weighing two options?

Tags: redundancy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Whether or not” vs. “whether”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/whether-or-not-vs-whether)

For example:

> "I was unsure whether to pity him."
>
> "I was unsure whether to pity him or not."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it redundant? Yes.  Is it unacceptable in speech or writing? No.  But ultimately, the question is if it is redundant, or not, which it is.

Just to be clear, because my redundancy joke might confuse:

- It is redundant to end with "or not," but redundancy is sometimes
  acceptable.
- It is cleaner and frankly more interesting to leave it as "I was
  unsure whether to pity him."
- The inclusion of "or not" conceptually reduces the statement to a
  binary choice between pity and no pity, whereas its exclusion leaves
  the statement more open-ended.

Comment: Sorry...is is acceptable or not to say 'whether X or not." ? Too many negatives to follow.

Comment: My apologies, I added a redundancy joke to my answer, which confused things.

Comment: -1: this is the most confusing answer on SE I've ever read.

Comment: Give it another shot now.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, could you then edit to say "Is it **acceptable** in speech or writing? **Yes.**" ? (emphasis here for clarity not for the suggestion).

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

It is redundant, though it might be useful for emphasis or clarity.

I used to write "whether or not" a lot, and I personally make a deliberate effort to remove the "or not"s.

In your example, "I am unsure whether to pity him", it is clear that there are two options: you might pity him, or you might not. Adding "or not" doesn't add any information. But it can be useful when you are trying to build dramatic tension into a sentence. Consider, "I don't like Bob, but he has a right to live, too." Versus, "I don't like Bob, but he may have a right to live ... or not."

Answer (score 0):

AHED defines [*whether*](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=whether):

> 1. Used in indirect questions to introduce one alternative: *We should
>      find out whether the museum is open.*
> 2. Used to introduce alternative possibilities: *Whether she wins or
>      whether she loses, this is her last tournament.*
> 3. Either: *He passed the test, whether by skill or luck.*

So:

1. In the sense of presenting **one** alternative, *or not* is redundant.
2. In the sense of introducing **alternative possibilities** or **either**, *or not* (shorthand for *or not pity him* in this case) is perfectly acceptable.

Looking at it yet another way:

> Possibility **A** = pity him
>
> Possibility **B** = **!A** = *not* pity him = *not*

So the OP's sentence becomes:

> I was unsure whether to **A** or **B**. (I was unsure whether to **pity him** or **not**.)

It's perfectly clear that *not* (alternative **B**) is acceptable, by sense 2 or sense 3 of the dictionary definition.

Comment: Downvoter: The OP is asking whether "or not" is redundant when weighing _two_ options; by the dictionary definition of _whether_, it isn't. What's your beef?

Comment: Your answer affirms (in "So: 1") that "or not" is redundant, then muddies the waters by implying that (2) is somehow different. Might it *not* be her last tournament if in fact she *draws?* In "correct" usage, there are *always* two alternatives in any construction involving "whether" - it's just that the second may be left implicit if it's simply the negation of the first. Things would only be different if OP's alternative were different *("I was unsure whether to pity him or laugh at him")*, which you have not considered.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In AHED's sense (1), n=1; in sense (2), n>1, so they are different. In sense (1), AHED disagrees that there are _always_ two alternatives; Oxford [concurs](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whether?q=whether), noting that _whether_ may express an enquiry.

Comment: In (1) there's no change in meaning with *We should find out whether the museum is open or not*, so there's an implicit alternative. Exactly the same applies to all other contexts you've quoted, including Oxford's "enquiry". I don't see why you think AHED *"disagrees there are always two alternatives"* - unless you're being misled by the archaic *"whether or no"*, which is not under consideration here. OP is simply asking whether [or not] there are a contexts where *"or not"* is **required**, as opposed to simply optional. The alternative *always* exists, even if only implicitly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "He was a cruel man, but fair."

Comment: Is that the polite way of saying *"He can be a bit anal sometimes"*? A quick check on my stats page confirmed my suspicion that you have a *very* high proportion of upvotes from me - which probably skewed me to downvote here over a fine point that I probably wouldn't have even registered with most other posters. You have set the bar a bit high, so I'm sure you'll have plenty of chances to knock my answers down if you feel a bit aggrieved! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Heh. No, I just recalled an old Python sketch that my colleagues and I used to quote at each other during design or review meetings: "I understand he also nailed your wife's head to a coffee table." "Yeah, well, he did do that. Yeah, yeah. He was a cruel man, but fair." Usually when someone nailed someone's head to the table, figuratively speaking.

Comment: haha I'd forgotten that one! Being somewhat impecunious these days, I guess I'd have to steal copies of MPFC via torrents. You're seriously tempting me into a life of crime! :)