# Is the "or not" in "whether or not" optional?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions, negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Whether or not” vs. “whether”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/whether-or-not-vs-whether)

I am not sure about the usage of *whether*. My confusion over it is whether *or not* is optional.   Suppose I have the following sentence:

> The results of the pathological test will definitely show whether the frail patient has an infection **or not**.

Is *or not* compulsory to make this sentence more appropriate, or is it optional?

Comment: As @jlovegren says, *[or not]* is superfluous, and if that's all the second condition consists of, you can discard it if you want. But in practice, we usually use **if** rather than **whether** in such contexts anyway. Note that even with **if**, you can still usually stick *[or not]* on the end. But that's not at all common, obviously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Whether* is used to form indirect polar (yes/no) questions. A polar question refers to two conditions, but they are logically related and so one condition can be inferred from the other.

From a functional standpoint, then, **[or not]** is superfluous. Not surprisingly, most indirect questions formed with *whether* can have **[or not]** omitted.

A separate issue to be raised, if you choose to keep **[or not]**, is where to place it. You can choose either:

> ...whether [or not] the frail patient has an infection.
>   ...whether the frail patient has an infection [or not].

The best guideline is that when the proposition under question is "heavy" (many words), use *whether or not...*, and when it is "light", use *whether...or not*.

Comment: and *"**if** the frail patient has an infection [or not]"*, but I would certainly balk at *"if **or not** the frail patient has an infection"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Is there any reason as to why you would say *if* rather than *whether* or it is just so? Is it about formality?

Comment: @Gigili: Well, I doubt native speakers would normally stop and think *"Shall I use **if** or **whether** here?"*. But **if** is shorter, and almost certainly it's far more common, so I imagine it would just tend to get used more often in contexts where both are equivalent. I don't think there's any real sense in which you could say *whether* is more "formal".

Comment: _Whether_ is the _Wh_-word for _Yes/No_ questions; it converts them to _Wh_-questions so that they can be embedded safely and marked as questions, even though they don't have subject-verb inversion or _Do_-support. E.g: _He asked me "Did you see it"?_ ==> _He asked me whether I saw it_. "Or not" is just a flourish, like a tag question.