# A better, more academic way of saying 'whether or not'

Tags: word-choice, grammar

This is my sentence, and I was hoping to make it sound more academic:

> The aim is to ascertain **whether or not** the actors from the two films analysed can be considered to be heroes

Is there a better, more academic way of saying '*whether or not*'?

Comment: Just *whether* would do; any other changes, and you're likely to change the meaning.

Comment: The way you used it sounds more emphatic to me.

Comment: I'd say it this way: "The aim is to determine whether the characters in the two films can be considered heroes". "Ascertain" is stilted & pretentious academic prose; "or not" is superfluous, & "whether" is more formal than "if" (_and I like it better: it's a matter of style & aesthetics, not grammar_); "to be" is superfluous; & "analysed" is probably unnecessarily redundant. If you're analyzing heroes in films, then you're probably discussing the **characters** rather than the actors, unless playing the characters was dangerous for the actors.

Comment: @Bill: whether or not *ascertain* is stilted and pretentious, *unnecessarily redundant* is redundantly unnecessary.

Comment: @TimL: Language is filled with redundancies. E.g., Chinese proves that the copula is redundant whenever the S has a predicate ADJ, but it's idiomatically necessary in English. Words like "whence" prove that for some, at least, repeating the meaning by adding the unnecessary "from" ("From whence did you come?") is necessary redundancy. And whenever ideas are difficult to grasp, redundancy seems necessary to ensure that they're understood. We have two kidneys & two lungs (if one fails, the other can take over), but only one heart. Even nature feels redundancy is sometimes necessary.

Comment: @TimL: Redundancy is sometimes necessary. Read the second paragraph in the [Wikipedia article about linguistic redundancies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(linguistics)).

Comment: @user21497 You didn't have to repeat yourself just now.

Comment: Frankly, you're setting yourself up for a bad experience by emphasizing the duality of the characters being heroes or not.

Comment: Related: [“Whether or not” vs. “whether”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3382)

Answer (score 6):

It OK to want to use language that's appropriate for your audience, but when one wants to "sound academic" one runs the risk of sounding artificial as well. It's best to write in as natural a style as possible, while remaining clear, and then to root out anything that's plainly inappropriate. There's nothing about **whether or not** that's unsuitable for an academic audience, though you could lose the **or not** without disadvantage. You could also replace **whether [or not]** with **if**.

> The aim is to ascertain if the actors from the two films analysed can be considered to be heroes.

or better

> The aim is to determine if the actors from the two films analysed can be considered to be heroes.

I like **determine** better here because **ascertain** is usually related to establishing *facts*, while here you are concerned with coming to a subjective judgment.

Now that I think about it, I'd also omit **to be** before **heroes**. Say out loud

> The aim is to determine if the actors from the two films analysed can be considered heroes.

and see if it isn't more pleasing than the alternative

> The aim is to determine if the actors from the two films analysed can
>   be considered to be heroes.

Comment: Thanks! My tutors and professors usually have problems with my writing style...I guess I should be more careful with the way I phrase things. I have omitted the 'to be' and used 'determined' instead of ascertain....thanks a lot!

Comment: I hope, Timer, that I don't get you into trouble! It's always possible that your tutors and professors really like language that I should consider pompous, artificial, verbose and unnecessarily abstruse or even obscurantist.

Comment: No worries! My tutor (for this piece) advised me to be more simple and clearer with my writing. I guess I can't go wrong if I write to the point, right? Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Yeah, I routinely have to prune stuff. Things like _in my opinion, x seems to be y_ would usually be much better if one lopped off expressions such as _in my opinion_ and said instead _x seems to be y_.
Just for funsies, would maybe _more simple and clearer_ be better as _simpler and clearer_?

Comment: @Animadversor: While I agree with your distinction between ascertaining a fact versus a subjective judgment, I don't agree with using **determine**, as it implies fact over judgment as well. "To determine" is defined as "ascertain or establish exactly by research or calculation" (again implying facts), and then there's derivations like "determinism", which argues that no free will (and by extension **no real subjectivity**) exists. It seems better to avoid the implication altogether ("to see if ...") or expressly state that it is a judgment ("to judge if ...").

Comment: @Flater: I think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

You could say "to ascertain the extent to which the actors can be considered...."

Or just say "whether", and drop the "or not".

Comment: Thank you, I like the way you have phrased the answer...it indicates there is no right or wrong answer.