# Does every "whether" have to be followed by an "or"?

Tags: conjunctions, correlative-conjunctions

Does every *whether* have to be followed by an *or*?

That is, is *whether* a **correlative conjunction** which requires *or* as a counterpart, or is *whether* able to stand alone with a single possibility?

Comment: It may be that [Fumblefingers' answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/54450/18696) answers this question. I'm not sure. @Citra, if you feel it does then comment here and we can mark the question accordingly.

Comment: Btw, "correlative" is a kind of coordination, but "whether" is a subordinator typically introducing subordinate interrogative clauses. Freeling10 has answered your question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not at all. The only time "whether" requires an "or" is when the phrase "whether or not" is being used. For instance, ***I wonder whether or not we'll go to the movies tonight.*** Otherwise, whether just by itself is fine. For example, ***I wonder whether we'll go to the movies tonight.*** It's essentially synonymous with the word "if."