# "as to if" grammatically acceptable?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

The question arises as to if the social unfolding was influenced by the movement rhythms.

This is a sentence from my thesis study, and I was wondering if "as to if" is grammatically acceptable, or do I need to restructure this sentence.

Comment: You should use *as to whether*.

Comment: @ Gustavson And "or not" should simply be implicit? https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3382/371882

Comment: "Whether" would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use 'whether' after propositions, and not 'if'. 'To', as used here, is a preposition.

> We use whether, not if, after prepositions:
>
> [talking about a trip to Australia for a year]
>
> We’re not interested in whether we get great jobs and that kind of
>   thing, we just want to have a good time.
>
> Not: We’re not interested in if we get great jobs and that kind of
>   thing …

**If, whether: typical errors:**

[If or whether (Cambridge Dictionaries Grammar)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/if-or-whether)